# Define a custom property for a FHIR resource instance

Tags: validation, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm trying to define a custom property for practitioner resources. But when I validate an instance against my structure definition it fails and have currently no idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
{
    "resourceType": "StructureDefinition",
    "url": "http://example.com/fhir/StructureDefinition/PractitionerProfile",
    "name": "PractitionerProfile",
    "status": "active",
    "kind": "resource",
    "abstract": false,
    "type": "Practitioner",
    "baseDefinition": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/Practitioner",
    "derivation": "specialization",
    "differential": {
        "element": [
            {
                "id": "Practitioner.telecom",
                "path": "Practitioner.telecom",
                "definition": "A contact detail for the practitioner, e.g. a telephone number or an email address.",
                "min": 1,
                "max": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "Practitioner.foo",
                "path": "Practitioner.foo",
                "definition": "A contact detail for the practitioner, e.g. a telephone number or an email address.",
                "min": 1,
                "max": "1",
                "type": [{
                  "code": "string"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
<Practitioner xmlns='http://hl7.org/fhir'>
    <meta>
        <profile value='http://example.com/fhir/StructureDefinition/PractitionerProfile' />
    </meta>
    <active value='true' />
    <foo value="bar"/>
    <telecom>
        <system value='phone' />
        <value value='555-101-0987' />
        <use value='home' />
    </telecom>
</Practitioner>
```

```
java -jar 'validator_cli.jar' -ig src/test/resources/integration/4.0/validate/ src/test/resources/integration/4.0/validate/valid-resource.xml -version 4.0 -tx n/a
FHIR Validation tool Version 5.4.2 (Git# 552ef55adaf0). Built 2021-05-21T18:15:07.271Z (7 days old)
  Java:   11.0.8 from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home on x86_64 (64bit). 4096MB available
  Paths:  Current = ~/fhir-rest, Package Cache = ~/.fhir/packages
  Params: -ig src/test/resources/integration/4.0/validate/ src/test/resources/integration/4.0/validate/valid-resource.xml -version 4.0 -tx n/a
Loading
  Load FHIR v4.0 from hl7.fhir.r4.core#4.0.1 - 4575 resources (00:04.0177)
  Load hl7.terminology#2.0.0 - 3749 resources (00:00.0799)
  Terminology server null - Version n/a: No Terminology Server (00:00.0000)
  Load src/test/resources/integration/4.0/validate/* load file: valid-resource.xml - ignored due to error: Unknown Content foo @  START_TAG seen ...<active value=\'true\' />\n    <foo value="bar"/>... @6:23
 - 2 resources (00:00.0056)
  Get set...  go (00:00.0045)
Validating
  Validate src/test/resources/integration/4.0/validate/valid-resource.xmlInternal error in location for message: 'Error @1, 1: Found / expecting a token name', loc = '/f:Practitioner', err = 'Undefined element 'foo''
 00:00.0649
Done. Times: Loading: 00:05.0356, validation: 00:00.0649. Memory = 199Mb

*FAILURE*: 2 errors, 0 warnings, 0 notes
  Error @ Practitioner (line 1, col43) : Practitioner.foo: minimum required = 1, but only found 0 (from http://example.com/fhir/StructureDefinition/PractitionerProfile)
  Error @ /f:Practitioner (line 6, col23) : Undefined element 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding custom properties is non-conformant.  If you have a custom requirement, you need to use the Practitioner.extension and define your element as a profile on the Extension data type.  Look at https://build.fhir.org/extensibility